# Javascript date mask is not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, mask

I have this Javascript that formats fields of type date in my html running fine in IE 8 :

```
Mask.prototype.attach = function (o, maFonction, event) {
    if ((o.readonly == null) || (o.readonly == false)) {
        o.onkeydown = new Function("return " + this.ref + ".isAllowKeyPress(event, this)");
        o.onkeyup = new Function("return " + this.ref + ".getKeyPress(event, this)");
        o.onblur = new Function("this.value = " + this.ref + ".format(this.value);" + maFonction );
        // AJOUT ONEM pour pouvoir donner le focus plus tard
        this.name = o.name;
        this.completname = o;
    }
}
```

The problem is that my application should be working in FireFox 24 esr as well. Which is not the case with the code above. It returns the error : ReferenceError: event is not defined.

How can I get this piece of code functions as it s supposed to be in Firefox? 
The script above is exctracted from a Javascript _MaskAPI().

Comment: There's really no need to be building functions dynamically here.

Comment: are you using this lib: http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/js/mask/ ???

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto : Yes I am using this lib: pengoworks.com/workshop/js/mask;

Comment: His current version has a different attach function. Have you tried using the latest version?